# HTML button not running JavaScript function and function output not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, button, io

Here's my code to calculate a person's age from inputting their birthday. I'm having trouble reading the birthday input and using in the getAge function. Also I cannot get the age to display in the second textfield. I am unsure how to correct these.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Age Calculator</title>
    <script>
    var birthday;

    function getAge(birth) {
        var bday = document.getElementById("bday");
        var ageDisplay = document.getElementById("ageDisplay");
        var today = new Date();
        var curr_date = today.getDate();
        var curr_month = today.getMonth() + 1;
        var curr_year = today.getFullYear();
        var pieces = birth.split('/');
        var birth_date = pieces[0];
        var birth_month = pieces[1];
        var birth_year = pieces[2];
        if (curr_month == birth_month && curr_date >= birth_date) return parseInt(curr_year - birth_year);
        if (curr_month == birth_month && curr_date < birth_date) return parseInt(curr_year - birth_year - 1);
        if (curr_month > birth_month) return parseInt(curr_year - birth_year);
        if (curr_month < birth_month) return parseInt(curr_year - birth_year - 1);
    }
    var age = getAge(birthday);
    ageDisplay.value = age
    </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:red">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Type your Date of Birth: </label>
            <input type="text" id="bday" />
            <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="getAge()" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label>Your Age is: </label>
            <input type="text" id="ageDisplay" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First

```
    function getAge(birth)
```

is not the same as

```
    getAge()
```

Second

```
    var pieces = birth.split('/');
```

should be

```
    var pieces = []; 
    pieces = birth.split('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that your user is inputting the date in the format that you want?
First you will have to make sure that they are inputting in the format that you want by giving them instructions in the placeholder of that input.
Let's assume that they are giving the input in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. Here is the solution using moment js.
The problem with your code is that you're not getting the value of bDay field.
Get the value like this

```
var bday = document.getElementById("bday").value;
```

Split it now

```
    var bDaySplit = bDay.split('/');
    var birthYear = bDaySplit[0], month = bDaySplit[1], day = bDaySplit[2];
    var currDate = moment(), // get the current date using monment js
        birthday = moment(birthYear + '/' + month + '/' + day); //
    var age = currDate.diff(birthday, 'years');
```

Now `age` is what you needed. Use it as you want.

Hope this helps.

P.S- Please do have a look at moment js library in case you don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this chunk of code in your script

```
var age = getAge(birthday);
ageDisplay.value = age
```

were **birthday** is undefined and causes an error in this line.

```
var pieces = birth.split('/');
```

that is why your function halts from working.

the second problem is I don't see any code in your function that gets data from birth element, to get the value

```
var bday = document.getElementById("bday").value;
```

Hope that helps